# SQL INSERT OR REPLACE gives error

Tags: sql

I have a table "bids" with some data already stored in it on my local. I have generated an insert query from the production database and I am trying to update the local db using an "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO" command:

```
INSERT  OR REPLACE  INTO 
 [dbo].[bids]([Id], [projectName], [country], [requestDate], 
              [custDecDate], [productType], [quantity], [forBid],
              [inBudgetPCS], [inBudgetTT], [chancesPCS], [chancesTT], 
              [valuePCS], [valueTT], [marginPCS], [marginTT], [notes], 
              [customerName])
```

I get two errors:

> Syntax not correct near REPLACE

and

> When Identity Insert is off it is not possible to insert an explicit value into column Identity....

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table has an IDENTITY column, you are not able to place a value into the column unless the IDENTITY INSERT is ON

To switch IDENTITY INSERT on/off, use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON
your INSERT statement
SET IDENTITY_INSERT INVACC OFF
```

Comment: Making progresses but now I get "...Violation of Primary Key..."

Comment: So then you are attempting to insert a value into a column that is a PK where a row already has that value in the table.

Comment: No problem. Could you mark my answer as the correct one for future ref please?